# Unable to Authenticate Azure AD Function App in PostMan

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-functions

I have enabled Azure AD for the function APP. AzureIdentity is my Function APP name.
[image: Azure Function]
I am using "\oauth2\token"

```
Get:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{my tenant ID}/oauth2/token

Headers: Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Body:

grant_type:client_credentials
resource:https://management.azure.com/
client_id:04e17699-64cd-42ec-96ec-23be345ef6ed
client_secret:{My secret}
```

[image: Get Authentication PostMan]
I am getting bearer token on Get request and passing it to the Function, but I am getting 401 Authentication error as below. Not sure where I am doing wrong.
[image: Function APP]

Please help how can I authenticate the function, Thank you.

Comment: the resource (resource:https://management.azure.com/) is wrong: it should be the client_id or resource_uri of your app registration.

Comment: Hello @Thomas, I have added client_id  and client_secret of App registration. Could you also specify what value I have to pass for ```resource_uri ```, Thank you

Comment: I mean the `resource` parameter should be `04e17699-64cd-42ec-96ec-23be345ef6ed` (client_id) or the `resource_uri` if you defined one on the app registration

Comment: @Thomas, I have modified ```resource``` parameter with values as ```04e17699-64cd-42ec-96ec-23be345ef6ed``` and removed ```client_ID``` , In Total  I am passing three parameter, ```resource,  client_secret, grant_type``` but I am getting same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'resource' parameter is not required, instead use 'scope' parameter

Scope here is my custom app ID which has a custom application role defined.

**scope ==> "04e17699-64cd-42ec-96ec-23be345ef6ed/.default"**

[image]

[image]

Comment: I was able to get it running. Please use scope 04e17699-64cd-42ec-96ec-23be345ef6ed/.default

Comment: Also use the v2.0 endpoint as mentioned in the screenshot above

Comment: @RoshanTolwani, you are my savior. I was following this guide (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/apis/webhooks/get-started-webhooks), but getting an error fetching token. Using scope solved it, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the same error as below:***

[image]
**To resolve the error, make use of `V2 endpoint` to generate the token like below:**

[image]

***Using the above generated access token, I am able to call the Function app successfully like below:***

[image]

Make sure to give the **code** you get in function URL as a value to **`x-function-key`** parameter.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Sridevi for the help. I am not sure if I can ask here, but is there a good course or links where I can clearly understanding on Azure AD in depth.